# How to remove excess top silk in Proteus?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, proteus, silkscreen

I have some markings on my plate made in silk and I believe they can hinder the welding, since a line is passing inside my pads, I know that when a silk line passes over the track there are no problems, but if a line passes over a pad and its welding mask? Wouldn't that be problematic?

Below are some attachments and markings where problems occur;
[image: img1]

[image: igm2]

Comment: It's not welding but soldering. There is a significant difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PCB manufacturer will **usually** remove any silkscreen that is in the same place as a resist hole. Normally, you won't have to worry about this, but double check with your manufacturer first. If you're using one of the prototyping services (Aisler, OSH Park, JLCPCB etc), you'll be fine.

Comment: I'm using PCBWay, but, i intend to use JLCPcb ( large scale )

Comment: @lukecross Go ahead then, you should be fine. Before getting the large order, do check directly, but at prototype level, I've never seen a manufacturer put silkscreen in resist holes.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Have a good day and take care with Covid19.